# mysql : delete rows where column = ID after delete ID

Tags: mysql

I have 1 table like this

```
ID   parent
1    null
2    1
3    1
```

now when I delete ID 1 I need auto delete all rows which parent = 1 . I try trigger a/b delete but give error for recursive trigger.

thanks

Comment: Look like he is storing  hierarchical data within MySQL as `adjacency list model` @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs then it's normal to store id and parent_id within the same table..

Comment: @RaymondNijland huh, maybe due to my lack of experience seeing that, not sure I've ever seen that before :) but I'll take your word for it and will remove my comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into FOREIGN KEY constraints and CASCADE rather than using triggers. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you cant use trigger for the same table which may result in dead lock so here you cant use trigger. 

 
You should use foreign key. Here is an example

```
ALTER TABLE `employee` ADD INDEX ( `parent_id` );


ALTER TABLE `employee` ADD CONSTRAINT `employee_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY ( `parent_id` ) REFERENCES `test`.`employee` (
`id`
) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ;
```

Here when you delete the parent data all the child rows will be deleted.

Comment: No you can use FOREIGN KEY in the same table. I have tried. May be you have to create table first then alter the table. I have tried it. Its working fine

Comment: I was also doubted. Then I tried it in my mysql database

Comment: Ok tested on MySQL 5.6, MySQL 5.7 and even MySQL 8.0 on sqlfiddle.com and db-fiddle.com all giving me the same error. 'Cannot add foreign key constraint'

Comment: I am using 5.5 Now I tested in 5.7 also its working. I think the issue is first you have to add index for the field(parent_id). may be thats the issue

Comment: @RaymondNijland Please check it and reply please

Comment: Learned something new today looks that you can indeed can use foreign key within the same table. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a95734/1 ... Didn't get it working with the `ALTER TABLE` commands will take a look into it when i have some more time..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Ok